# Incrementing a date in a dataview by 1

Tags: sharepoint-online, xslt

I need to increase a date field by 1 day.  The xslt I have which displays this date is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(pubDate),1041,'yyyy年 MM月 dd日')"/>
```

I tried to add one day with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(pubDate),1041,'yyyy年 MM月 dd日')+1"/>
```

but then the dates change to NaN.  Is there a way to accomplish this with XSLT?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try below line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(pubDate),1041,'yyyy年 MM月 dd日') + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121009/how-to-increment-1-day-in-date-using-xslt) link which might be helpful.